# Java. Сложение двух цветов для получения третьего

Tags: java, изображения

Интересует такой вопрос: возможно ли в Java при накладывании двух изображений получить результат их слияния без полного перекрытия вторым изображением, если быть точнее, то получить результат как на картинке.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Например, есть два изображения, на первом что-то зеленое, на втором что-то синее, и при слиянии зеленого с синим получить голубой, как на примере слияния RGB (выше). Код, что приведен ниже, не делает "сложение" цветов, он просто переписывает все пиксели первого последним изображением. Спасибо.

```
public static void merge() throws IOException {
    File green = new File("C:\\green.png");
    File blue = new File("C:\\blue.png");
    File combined = new File("C:\\combined.png");


    BufferedImage green_image = ImageIO.read(green);
    BufferedImage blue_image = ImageIO.read(blue);

    int w = Math.max(green_image.getWidth(), blue_image.getWidth());
    int h = Math.max(green_image.getHeight(), blue_image.getHeight());
    BufferedImage combinedBuf = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    Graphics g = combinedBuf.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(blue_image, 0, 0, null);
    g.drawImage(green_image, 0, 0, null);

    ImageIO.write(combinedBuf, "PNG", combined);
}
```

Comment: Думаю надо покапать в сторону `setPaintMode`

Comment: Из коробки, по-моему, нет. Т.е. механизм `Composite` в наличии, но нужна реализация аддитивного и субтрактивного смешения цветов. Можно взять [`BlendComposite`](https://github.com/arotenberg/swingx/blob/f805d03fba94ab14312d8f83fbf6ee16e454f1ef/swingx-graphics/src/main/java/org/jdesktop/swingx/graphics/BlendComposite.java) из swingx.

Answer (score 0):

### Мне удалось сделать это, создав свой `Composite`:

---

#### `merge()`

```
public static void merge() throws IOException {
    File green = new File("C:\\green.png");
    File blue = new File("C:\\blue.png");
    File combined = new File("C:\\combined.png");


    BufferedImage green_image = ImageIO.read(green);
    BufferedImage blue_image = ImageIO.read(blue);

    int w = Math.max(green_image.getWidth(), blue_image.getWidth());
    int h = Math.max(green_image.getHeight(), blue_image.getHeight());
    BufferedImage combinedBuf = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    Graphics g = combinedBuf.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(blue_image, 0, 0, null);
    g.setComposite(LightComposite.INSTANCE); // <------ Добавил
    g.drawImage(green_image, 0, 0, null);

    ImageIO.write(combinedBuf, "PNG", combined);
}
```

### LightComposite.java

```
import java.awt.Composite;
import java.awt.CompositeContext;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.ColorModel;
import java.awt.image.Raster;
import java.awt.image.WritableRaster;

public class LightComposite implements Composite {

    public static LightComposite INSTANCE = new LightComposite();

    private LightContext context = new LightContext();

    @Override
    public CompositeContext createContext(ColorModel srcColorModel,
            ColorModel dstColorModel, RenderingHints hints) {
        return context;
    }
    
    
    private static class LightContext implements CompositeContext {

        @Override
        public void compose(Raster src, Raster dstIn, WritableRaster dstOut) {
            int w = Math.min(src.getWidth(), dstIn.getWidth());
            int h = Math.min(src.getHeight(), dstIn.getHeight());

            int[] srcRgba = new int[4];
            int[] dstRgba = new int[4];

            for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
                    src.getPixel(x, y, srcRgba);
                    dstIn.getPixel(x, y, dstRgba);
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                        dstRgba[i] = (int) ((dstRgba[i] + srcRgba[i]));
                        if(dstRgba[i] > 255) {
                            dstRgba[i] = 255;
                        }
                        if(dstRgba[i] < 0) {
                            dstRgba[i] = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    dstOut.setPixel(x, y, dstRgba);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void dispose() {
        }
    }
}
```